# CF PUSH FAILS saying "The route is invalid"

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to push a simple hello world app to cloud foundry running on AWS cloud foundry community AMI. I am able to login and create space but when i try to push the application, i am getting the following error

**"Server error, status code: 400, error code:210001, message: The route is invalid: [domain invalid_relation]"**

I am using cf CLI version 6.6.2 and tried mapping route to app using

**create-route**

and deleting the route but i get the message

**"DOMAIN NOT FOUND"** in both the cases.

Does anybody know what might be causing this error ??

Comment: Can you post the output of the following command? `cf domains`.  Also can you post your command you pushed your app with and also if you have manifest.yml file can you please post that as well?

Comment: Also tell us what release of CF you're running server side.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the domain first;

```
$ cf create-domain myorg mydomain.com
$ cf create-route myspace mydomain.com -n www
```